# How old is Alan Partridge meant to be?

Tags: comedy, sitcoms

Across the many series that the character of Alan Partridge has featured (from The Day Today, through I'm Alan Partridge and to the current iteration in This Time), one thing that's puzzled me is how old he's meant to be. I'm not sure if a direct birth date is given in the 'autobiography' I, Partridge, he's clearly in his early 20's and 30's during Knowing Me, Knowing You and in both series of I'm Alan Partridge it's implied he's in his late 40's/early 50's with children that are in their late teens/early 20's - but this takes place only 3 years after the 'cancellation' of Knowing Me Knowing You. This however seems like it gets retconned by the time we reach Alpha Papa, where according to the show's timeline he should be in his early 60's but is clearly a lot younger. Has he aged due to his divorce in series 1 of I'm Alan Partridge?

I know the show has played fast and loose with time in the past but in recent years the Gibbons brothers have made obvious attempts to tie the characters life into one consistent timeline, and the fact that Steve Coogan appears AS Alan Partridge live and on various chat shows implies that the character must have a definitive age. So what is it?

Comment: I don't know for certain, so just as a comment, but my guess is they're slightly squeezed his age as he got older. Steve was about 29 when he first played Alan in his 40's, so as Coogan gets older he's now reaching the age Alan is now playing. In only a few years they'll stop squeezing time, as they'll be in sync. Alan might be early 60's but Steve is now 57.